# Various problems with IUPLua

Tags: lua, compiler-errors, cmake, iup

I've been trying, for a few days, to get a simple test case (matrix.wlua from the IUP documentation's examples) to work properly.

IUPLua isn't in LuaRocks, so I had to install LuaDist and modify my path; when I then tried to compile iup (including the flag `-DGTK2_INCLUDE_DIRS=/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0;/usr/include/glib-2.0;/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include;/usr/include/gtk-2.0;/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/include;/usr/include/gtk-2.0;/usr/include/cairo;/usr/include/pango-1.0;/usr/include/atk-1.0` in order for the gdk-pixbuf headers to be properly included), the following error message showed for almost every single GTK-related file being compiled:

```
[ 35%] Building C object CMakeFiles/iup.dir/src/gtk/iupgtk_common.c.o
In file included from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gdk/gdkcairo.h:28:0,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gdk/gdk.h:33,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtk.h:32,
                 from /home/archie/luadist/tmp/iup-3.5/LuaDist-iup-203b27f/src/gtk/iupgtk_common.c:12:
/usr/include/gtk-2.0/gdk/gdkpixbuf.h:43:43: error: unknown type name ‘GdkPixbuf’
```

Some digging around in my system include files with `grin` determined that the declaration listed in the GdkPixBuf documentation, `typedef struct _GdkPixbuf GdkPixbuf`, did not actually exist in any file that my package manager tells me was installed by gdk-pixbuf.

My next attempt was to download the IUP dist and manually disable the options in the `CMakeLists.txt` file to use GTK2. It then compiled, linking to OpenMotif, and the provided C program "iuptest" worked perfectly. CDLua and IMLua also compiled perfectly and installed to /usr/local/lib/lua. However, the compilation of IUPLua halted with the following error message:

```
[ 98%] Building C object CMakeFiles/iupluaweb.dir/srclua5/il_webbrowser.c.o
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `/usr/lib/libiupweb.so', needed by `iupluaweb.so'.  Stop.
```

I am not familiar enough with CMake or C to know how to fix this, and I can't really believe that such library would have such flaws without there being relevant search engine results for either of those error messages (there aren't). I think that these tribulations may be the result of some mistake on my part. Any ideas as to what the mistake might be and/or how to fix it?